# Adjunction in Abelian Categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, adjoint-functors, functors

Let $C,D$ be arbitrary categories and $F:C\to D, G:D\to C$ functors. We say $F,G$ are adjoint if for every $X\in C, Y  \in D$ there is an isomorphism of Hom-Sets between $Hom_D(FX,Y)\cong Hom_C(X,GY)$, which is natural in $X$ and $Y$.

If for example $C,D$ are abelian, we have an abelian group structure on the Hom-Sets. Does anything interesting happen if we add the condition that the natural isomorphism must be an isomorphism of abelian groups and not just sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every adjunction between abelian categories in fact preserves the abelian group structure on the Hom-sets.  First, note that $F$ and $G$ will both preserve biproducts (since $F$ preserves colimits and $G$ preserves limits).  It follows that $F$ and $G$ preserve the addition operation on Hom-sets, since it can be constructed in terms of biproducts.  But now the adjunction bijection $\operatorname{Hom}_D(FX,Y)\to\operatorname{Hom}_C(X,GY)$ is given by taking a morphism $FX\to Y$, applying $G$ to get a morphism $GFX\to GY$, and then composing with the unit of the adjunction $X\to GFX$.  Both steps of this preserve addition of morphisms, and hence so does the adjunction bijection.